# $w = 0001000 \in L'$, but this $w$ is not in $L$?

Tags: logic, automata, regular-language

Suppose if $L ⊆ Σ^∗$ is a regular language then the following language is also regular:

$$L' = \{w\mid ∃x, y ∈ Σ^∗ : w = xy ∧ yx ∈ L\}$$

For a simple example, let *L* be given by the regular expression $0^∗1$, so that $L$ is the set of words over $Σ=\{0,1\}$ consisting of a (possibly empty) string of zeroes followed by a single $1$. Then $L′$ is given by the regular expression $0^∗10^∗$ and is the set of words over $Σ$ that contain exactly one $1$.

So according to this example, $w = 0001000 \in L'$, but this $w$ is not in $L$. How is that possible?

Comment: $L$ will always be a subset of $L'$, because if $w\in L$, we can let $x=\epsilon$ and $y=w$ to see that $w\in L'$, but there is no reason to think that $L'$ will always be a subset of $L$, and indeed this example shows that it need not be.

Comment: If $w = 0001000$, then we can take $x = 0001$ and $y = 000$. Then $w = xy$ and $yx = 0000001 \in L$. This shows $w \in L'$, but since $w$ does not end in a $1$, it cannot be in $L$.